# codeblocks fprintf replace '\n' by 0x0D 0x0A

Tags: windows, addition, codeblocks

With CodeBlocks (Windows OS) I have a strange case where CodeBlocks add '`\r`' to the '`\n`' at the `fprintf` fonction.

```
fprintf(fichier.txt, "%s",  "test\n");
fprintf(fichier.txt, "%s",  "test\n");
```

In the output file `fichier.txt` I can read in hexa:

> 74 65 73 74 0D 0A 74 65 73 74 0D 0A

How could I do to avoid these `0x0D` additive char? Is it a codeblocks option?

Thanks a lot
Mich

Comment: Codeblocks is not unique in this, any compiler designed for Windows should behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

You must create or open a file in binary mode:

```
FILE * file = fopen("fichier.txt", "wb");
fprintf(file, "%s",  "test\n");
```

See more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).